# quickJS documentation and/or well commented projects

Tags: quickjs

I am porting an in-house system from [Duktape](https://duktape.org) to [quickJS](https://bellard.org/quickjs/) to take advantage of the support for ES6 features and good module support (including dynamic imports).

Have ported some simple class libraries to be imported as shared object modules. But getting stumped with more advanced inter-operation issues. `quickjs.h` contains approximately 400 entries, but there are less than 2 pages of documentation for the C-API.

Any suggestions as to where more detailed documentation could be found?
Failing that pointers to any well documented project using quickJS might help. *Yes, I have `Googled` and haven't found anything useful.*

Answer (score 4):

I am also in the same boat,QuickJS docs & examples are hard to find here are the best ones I found so far :

- https://github.com/sntg-p/QuickJS-raylib : very nice as it wraps a good portion of the relatively large RayLib API
- https://github.com/saghul/txiki.js might also have some nice things (as it wraps libuv amomngs other things
- a more simple example https://github.com/calbertts/async-quickjs

hope the above examples help !

Comment: I posted about exposing C structs inside QuickJS - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70123636/use-quickjs-to-modify-preferences-and-global-variables . Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.