# Use QuickJS to modify preferences and global variables

Tags: quickjs

I am interested in using QuickJS to modify preferences in a C++ app. So, there is a preference variable called
`int myPref = 0`

I want to expose this as a JS variable called
`jsPref`

Then the user can modify this directly via JS using
`jsPref = 1`

This can be extended to a struct - where one can define
`struct myPref { int a, int b};` which is exposed as a global in JS as `jsPref`

Inside the JS script, I wish to call

```js
jsPref.a = 1;
jsPref.b = 2;
```

and the assignments should be reflected in the C struct `myPref`
Sadly, I do not even have sample code on exposing a struct. After searching, I only came up with examples of C/C++ functions exposed as JS methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at e.g. `JS_AddIntrinsicAtomics` in the QuickJS source code.  It uses `JS_SetPropertyFunctionList` to create an object whose properties are defined by a simple array of structures, with the help of some convenience macros.

Instead of `JS_CFUNC_MAGIC_DEF`, you can use `JS_CGETSET_DEF` or `JS_CGETSET_MAGIC_DEF` to define custom properties with getters and setters.  Since the contents of the `JSContext` structure are not exposed in the public API, you will have to use `JS_GetGlobalObject` to access the global object.  Otherwise though, what you need to do is substantially the same.

This should look something like this:

```c
// those will be called when jsPref.a is accessed
static JSValue pref_a_get(JSContext *ctx, JSValueConst this_val);
static JSValue pref_a_set(JSContext *ctx, JSValueConst this_val, JSValueConst value);

// those will be called when jsPref.b or jsPref.c is accessed and receive 123 or 456 respectively in the `magic` parameter
static JSValue pref_bc_get(JSContext *ctx, JSValueConst this_val, int magic);
static JSValue pref_bc_set(JSContext *ctx, JSValueConst this_val, JSValueConst value, int magic);

static const JSCFunctionListEntry prefs_obj_props[] = {
    JS_CGETSET_DEF("a", pref_a_get, pref_a_set),
    JS_CGETSET_MAGIC_DEF("b", pref_bc_get, pref_bc_set, 123),
    JS_CGETSET_MAGIC_DEF("c", pref_bc_get, pref_bc_set, 456),
};

static const JSCFunctionListEntry prefs_obj[] = {
    JS_OBJECT_DEF("jsPref", prefs_obj_props, countof(prefs_obj_props), JS_PROP_WRITABLE | JS_PROP_CONFIGURABLE ),
};

void create_prefs_obj(JSContext *ctx)
{
    JSValue globalThis = JS_GetGlobalObject(ctx);
    JS_SetPropertyFunctionList(ctx, globalThis, prefs_obj, countof(prefs_obj));
    JS_FreeValue(ctx, globalThis);
}
```

The above defines the struct variation.  For a single preference, you can put a `JS_CGETSET_DEF` definition directly in the `prefs_obj`, to define an accessor-based property of the global object.

Note that properties defined using `JS_CGETSET_DEF` are configurable, which means user code can perform e.g. `delete jsPrefs.a;` and lose access to the exposed property.  If you want to prevent that, you will have to write your own helper macro so that you can set property flags yourself.  You may also want to have a look at `JS_PreventExtensions`, to catch user code attempting to write to a preference that doesn’t exist.  If you want to use that, you may need to create the preferences object with `JS_NewObject`, define its properties with `JS_SetPropertyFunctionList`, seal it and add it to the global object manually, with `JS_DefinePropertyValue`, instead of doing everything at once with just one `JS_SetPropertyFunctionList` call:

```c
void create_prefs_obj(JSContext *ctx)
{
    JSValue globalThis = JS_GetGlobalObject(ctx);

    // null prototype to avoid namespace clashes
    JSValue prefsObj = JS_NewObjectProto(ctx, JS_NULL);

    // define preference properties
    JS_SetPropertyFunctionList(ctx, prefsObj, prefs_obj, countof(prefs_obj));

    // catch user code writing to nonexistent properties
    JS_PreventExtensions(ctx, prefsObj);

    // expose the preferences object
    JS_DefinePropertyValueStr(ctx, globalThis, "jsPref", prefsObj, PROP_CONFIGURABLE | PROP_WRITABLE);
    JS_FreeValue(ctx, globalThis);
}
```

Comment: This is fantastic. Thanks. Why would anyone need a JS_CGETSET_DEF vs JS_CGETSET_MAGIC_DEF ? Is `magic` used as some sort of id ?

Comment: QuickJS itself uses it e.g. to implement RegExp flag properties (see `js_regexp_get_flag`). `magic` is just an opaque value, to be used as the callback pleases.